# Angular 2 app works on work computer, home computer it is not working correctly

Tags: angular

I am not sure how to ask this because I don't think it is a coding issue as much as it may be my environment? At work approximately 2 weeks ago I installed angular CLI. My app works correctly. At home, I install angular CLI a while ago, months ago I think. Anyhow, this code doesn't render to screen on my home computer:

```
                              <li class="center" *ngFor="let link of dataenjoylinks">
                                <p>{{link.show}},&nbsp;
                                  <a href="{{link.link}}?utm_source={{utmSource}}&utm_medium={{utmMedium}}&utm_campaign={{utmCampaign}}&utm_content=enjoy-{{link.show}}">
                                    <i>{{link.title}}</i>
                                  </a>, {{link.date}}</p>
                                <p style="max-width: 600px; text-align:center;">
                                  <button (click)="this.removeLink(link)">Remove Link</button>
                                </p>
                              </li>
```

I console.log(dataenjoylinks) when the user adds the link, and it contains the data. Again, this works fine at my work computer.

Is it my version of Angular I am using at home? Here is the version I currently use for home computer:

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.4
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.4
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.4
@angular/cli                      6.1.4
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.4
@schematics/angular               0.7.4
@schematics/update                0.7.4
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. My default browser is Avast Secure Browser. When I run ng serve --open it opens in that browser.

I switched to chrome, and it works now. I wasted a few hours trying to figure this out so if anyone else runs into the same problem and you are using an odd browser try changing it.

Answer (score 0):

It's doubtful, assuming that your able to compile and run the Angular project on your home machine. It's probably project or cache related. Perhaps missing or out of date dependencies / files?

Try these steps in the order:

1. Refresh your browser cache, and ensure you are compiling the project. See if the issue persists, if not preceed to the next step
2. Refresh your local project by pulling the latest changes from the repository (that is if you obtained the code via a repo), then refresh dependencies with npm i, and compile again, and check issue again
3. If that doesn't work, compare your local files with a copy of the files on your work machine to verify there aren't any missing files.
4. Worst case, install the exact version of angular cli, npm, and nodejs as your work machine

HTH

Comment: I added the answer above. It ended up being the browser I was using. I switched to chrome and it works as intended. I was using Avast Secure Browser. Thanks for taking the time to help me, I appreciate it!